# What do I do when I get an "Iterator does not have appropriate bounds" error?

Tags: warning-messages

I used this as input

```
Table[600851475143/i , {i, 1, 600851475143}]
```

but  got an error

```
Table::iterb:Iterator {i,1,600851475143} does not have appropriate bounds.
```

But this gives me no error why?:

```
Table[600851475143/i , {i, 1, 13}]
```

Comment: If the error message is followed by two little angle brackets (>>) you can click on these to read more about the error. I didn't realize this for a while... :)

Comment: LoL. I was just going to write the same question for the third problem of the project Euler, then the SE suggested your question. I laughed when I saw the number.

Comment: I solved it like this: `Select[Divisors[600851475143], PrimeQ]`

Comment: `Last[Select[Divisors[600851475143], PrimeQ]]` for more speed!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is because the number you used is extremely large.  The number of iterations supported (in either `Table` or `Do`) seems to be $2^{31}-1$, i.e. the maximum size of a signed machine integer.  I believe this is also an upper bound on the size of an array in Mathematica.

This limitation is not unreasonable: the size of the `Table` you are trying to construct is too large to fit into memory anyway.  (Even if each element could be stored on a single byte, you'd be asking for 600 GB of memory.)

If you change the step size in the iterator to a large number, it will work:

```
Table[600851475143/i, {i, 1, 600851475143, 100000000}]
```

Comment: @Szabolcs This is weird, isn't 1 the default step size? I did `Table[x, {x, 1, 10}]` and it gives me `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}`.

Comment: @Szabolcs I also tried the same with this `600851475143/Range[1, 600851475143, 1]` and it still gives me this error.

Comment: @Gustavo Yes, 1 is the default step size.  I don't understand your comment, can you explain?

Comment: Is this max number of iterations the same on x86-64 systems?

Comment: @Ruslan Probably not.  Why don't you try it?

Comment: @Szabolcs I don't currently have access to such a system. Also, it seems it'll take quite some time to check more than $2^{31}-1$ iterations. I hoped you might know from some docs.

Comment: @Ruslan The command quoted in the question does not give an error on a 64 bit system like it does on a 32 bit one, so I guess that this limitation is not there on 64 bit systems.  I do not know where this is documented (if it is at all).

Answer (score 8):

As Szabolcs has said the trouble lies in the size of the table you are trying to produce.

It does not however stop you plotting the function you want to investigate.

```
Plot[600851475143/i, {i, 1, 600851475143}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or sampling the function at discrete steps and then plotting it as in:

```
z=Table[600851475143/i, {i, 1, 600851475143, 10^6}];
ListPlot[z];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]